# How to turn selectize input items editable?

Tags: javascript, yii2

I need the elements of the "selectize-input" list to be editable, that is, when I write a name in the text field, a list of countries appears, but once I have selected a country, I can no longer use the delete button to  delete the selected country in order to enter a different string.  I have to explore a long list to choose another country, and that is quite annoying.

The JavaScript file code is too long, so I can't show it here.  I just need some ideas to be able to solve this problem as quickly as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be really better to have at least one sample code even with few elements. You will have answers more easily!

Answer (score 0):

You must insantiate the `remove_button` plugin as it states in the documentation, inside pluginOptions:

```
    'pluginOptions' => [
                 // define list of plugins 
                'plugins' => ['remove_button'],
    ]
```

But for select list I would personally recommend to switch to [Kartik select2](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2), it has too many conveniences to not use it in favour of default plugins.